# Enable/disable Windows 7 device via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, drivers

I have a device that I often enable and disable using the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager). I'd like to write a script to do this programmatically (that is, using the command line). I saw a program called `devcon` that works for Windows 2000, Windows XP and [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003), but I need one that works for Windows 7. Is there one freely available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Download the [WDK Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) from Microsoft.
2. Use the [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) to extract the contents of the ISO to a temporary location... or use whatever method you like to mount and get inside the ISO.
3. You can use the same tool to extract the install file "WDK\setuptools_x64fre.msi" to a temporary directory.
4. In that temporary directory you will find "WinDDK\7600.16385.win7_wdk.100208-1538\tools\devcon\amd64\devcon.exe".  It has been tested to work with Win7x64, and it is part of the most recent Windows Driver development kit.

So, there is Devcon.exe for Windows 7 for you.  It works with Windows 7, and it is free.

Instructions taken from the [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/devcon-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7/9abcc12c-d7db-4249-aec4-fc4ff0ea6ee8) forum.

Comment: This [gentleman here](http://techlikes.com/2010/09/25/devcon-problem-in-windows-7-solved.html#comment-196743312) was kind enough to upload the file by itself, so that you don't have to download a 700mb ISO just to extract it. Worked fine for me.

Comment: Make sure to also extract setuptools_x64fre_cab001.cab, because actually that cab file contains devcon, not the msi.

Comment: https://wp.me/p7I9kP-w shows how to download only the piece of the ISO you need, shows Win 7, 8, & 10, x64 & x86.

Answer (score 45):

[DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) is another way to do this - and it's a lot easier to acquire than devcon.exe, but still free.

I use the following command in a batch file to use disable/enable a device on my wife's laptop when we need it:

```
devmanview.exe /disable_enable "SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller"
```

You can also create a regular shortcut, edit its properties and add the parameters in the *Target* field.

Comment: This worked in Vista too.

Comment: It makes me both sad and happy that a tool that does this exists.

Comment: Site does not mention supported systems but it works fine on Windows 8.1 64-bit (used the "DevManView for x64 systems" version).

Comment: worked for me in 2015 april - win7-64

Comment: It would be best if there was an option to toggle the device state.

Comment: In case anyone wants to tie this to a key combo, I strongly recommend [AutoHotKey][2] for this. I'm using the following script to enable/disable my laptop's touchscreen by pressing ```Ctrl```-```Alt```-```T```:

    ```!^T::```
    ```MsgBox, Enabling Touch in 3 seconds...```
    ```Run, DevManView.exe /disable_enable "HID-compliant touch screen", C:\Program Files\DevManView```
    ```return```

Comment: After trying `devcon` and `pnputil`, this is the only program that allowed me to disable/enable my device without requiring a reboot! Life saver!

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 8, there is WDK 8.1 available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513

The small setup binary allows to download (without installing WDK) (~500MB) and without iso-container.

Searched cabs for devcon.exe but names are scrambled. Used Universal Extractor to extract "..\Installers\Windows Driver Kit-x86_en-us.msi" - ends with an error. However, got the file I need: "...\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x64\devcon.exe"

Tool needs to run with Admin privs to have effect.