# Restart CDROM service under Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, laptop, compact-disc, reboot

My laptop DELL XPS M1330 has CDROM drive (MATSHITADVD+-RW UJ-857G), unfortunately this drive sometimes is not responsive when I load CD. Loading and unloading CDs don't help. In that case I just restart laptop and this helps for some time. How can I restart only this part of windows which is responsible for CD drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to unload and load the driver.

Have you tried disabling and then enabling the cdrom drive in device manager?

Or uninstalling/installing the device in device manager (just make sure you don't check 'uninstall driver files')?

To enter the device manager hit `windows key` + `R` and then type `devmgmt.msc`

Comment: This action of load/unload driver, can be done from command line?

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/429016/enable-disable-windows-7-device-via-command-line) are instruction on how to do it with the command line