# Windows Multipoint Server 2012 Audio Devices Disabled on Startup

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-server-2012

I have a fresh install of Windows Multipoint Server 2012. When I first boot, and look at the device manager, the audio output devices are there, proper drivers and everything, just disabled. I can manually enable it and the audio works fine. After I enable the audio device and reboot, it is once again disabled. There doesn't appear to be any conflict, but it just boots up with the audio device disabled.

How can I make the audio device start enabled on boot?

Running a Dell XPS 7800, Quad-core i7, 24 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this related question: [Enable/disable Windows 7 device via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/429016/enable-disable-windows-7-device-via-command-line) and used [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) to enable the audio via the command line using batch file on startup.  I realize that this is not solving the root problem, but it is an effective work-around.

Here's how I did it.

- Download [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) (Making sure to download the x64 version and unzip it into `c:\Utilities`)
- create `enable_audio.cmd` with one line: `c:\Utilities\devmanview.exe /enable "Realtek High Definition Audio"` (your device name may vary, it just needs to be spelled exactly as it appears in the Device Manager)
- Create a task in the Task Scheduler to run on startup whether logged in or not.

Now on startup, Windows Server will boot and enable the audio device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Open Registry, go to `HK_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS MULTIPOINT SERVER` then add new **DWORD : DisableSystemAudioDevices** with value = **0** (if you want to return to default setting of WMS2012 change value to 1).