# enable/disable a device using command line instead of device manager

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Is there any way to write a batch file in windows to read the status of a a device and enable it if it is currently disabled?

Problem is, some times when I start the windows, the audio device is disabled (I don't know why). So I have to go to device manager and right click on the audio device and select "enable". Therefore, I am planning to write a script or batch file to scan for the devices and enable the device automatically.

However I don't know the if windows commands supports such feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable/disable Windows 7 device via command line](http://superuser.com/questions/429016/enable-disable-windows-7-device-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this question already?
[Previous Question](https://superuser.com/questions/429016/enable-disable-windows-7-device-via-command-line)

Comment: ok please remove your answer so that I can delete the post. Seems to be duplicate

Comment: it says there should be a "delete" link between edit and flag. It does not appear for me i must not have the reputation yet