# How to change (via command-line) setting for "use device" / "don't use device" on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, audio, microphone

I have a microphone which does not have an off switch.  It is USB and, if connected, it is powered on.  Normally, I don't want the microphone on so I have to go into "Sounds", right-click the device, and select "Enable/Disable" or select "Properties" then "Use this device/Don't use this device".

It would be more convenient to have an icon or something I could just click once to enable/disable.  I've tried some of the suggestions with devcon but it enables/disabled the driver itself and doesn't really work well.  Also tried nircmd but couldn't find anything that really met my need.

Comment: [Enable/disable Windows 7 device via command line](http://superuser.com/q/429016). See the highest voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to script it, you could use the keyboard shortcut

<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>escape</kbd>

(well, it seemed short to me)

Comment: So, that opens Device Manager.  But: 1) I still have to locate the driver and disable it, and 2) I don't want to disable the driver.  At this point, I've added a short-cut to my desktop for the Sound control panel applet.  But there, I still have to select the "Recording" tab, then right-click the microphone to enable/disable.  NOTE: That this does not enable/disable the driver but the use of the driver by the audio subsystem.

Comment: Well, I admit I was on Win 7, and WINDOWS+X opens the Mobility manager there.  I guess MS changed it.  Maybe they decided the differently abled didn't mind a few more clicks.  I guess they and us will get over it.